# Leak Canary UI showing every time for *excluded* leaks in Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I attempted using Leak Canary several times, and always end up disabling it.

My main issue is that it constantly detects leaks caused by the framework (or manufacturer's versions of the Android Software), so every time I close my app, the UI of Leak Canary pops up with false negatives which is pretty annoying.

I noticed there's logic for exclusions, and they're declared in AndroidExcludedRefs.java. My false negatives usually show up among the ones declared there (matching the Android version code criteria correctly), but the are still causing Leak Canary to show a UI every time I close my app, even if they show up marked as *(excluded)*.

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to prevent the UI from popping up every time there's an Excluded leak?

Thanks!